# Internal latch plate stuck in latch bore?

Tags: doors, lock, hole, doorknob, stuck

I am trying to replace my interior door knobs and am really struggling to remove the latch in my bathroom door. The latch plate (*which goes  into the latch bore*) was painted over so I assumed that’s why it wouldn't budge.

I was able to disassemble the latch while it was still in the door and remove it that way, however the latch plate is still stuck in the latch bore and possibly still a part of the latch.
I’ve tried to remove it with pliers but have just managed to bend or break everything I can manage to grab onto.

Is there any way to remove this?

Is it possible that this is built into or glued into the door?

Am I going to need to replace the whole door?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the edge of the door? Are there screws that are still holding it in place but are, possibly, so painted over that you can't easily see them? I would think that anything that goes into that latch bore should pull from the edge, not into the main bore.

Comment: Agreed with @FreeMan. You're not supposed to pull that out from the handle hole. From your picture, look at the right edge of your door because there should be a mortise/face plate. Above all else, look at the instructions for your new handle and work backwards; it will answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Use a hammer and punch/chisel, angled into the latch opening, to knock the bolt out of the door.  You wan to push it OUT, not pull it IN.

Answer (score 2):

Door bolts are installed from the outside, so you'd remove it from the outside.

Cut the paint around the trim ring or plate *on the edge of the door* to prevent tearing, then tap the bolt out from inside the large bore.

Comment: If the the bolt has a trim ring, (*wedge type collar in place of a trim plate*),  as opposed to a mortised  plate, then it can be **difficult** to tap/push it out. Sometimes I  use two tools, one to provide a fulcrum point for the other in order to lever it out.